# Abnormal behaviour of free() in C

Tags: c, pointers, free

**Note:** I apologise if the question is too long or does not fit the format for SO. If not on the proper site, pls suggest for which StackExchange sites the question would be more appropriate.
I have been following [this](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_avl.aspx) tutorial about AVL Trees and decided to add a BFS search for the tree. This is my implementation (parts of it) -

```
void *dequeue(struct q *q_instance)
{
    struct q_node *temp;
    void *jsw_node_ptr;

    if (q_instance->beg == NULL)
        return NULL;

    temp = q_instance->beg;
    jsw_node_ptr = temp->node;

    if (q_instance->beg == q_instance->end)
        q_instance->beg = q_instance->end = NULL;
    else
        q_instance->beg = q_instance->beg->next;

    free(temp);

    return jsw_node_ptr;
}

void bfs_order(struct jsw_node *root)
{
    struct q *q_instance = NULL;
    struct jsw_node *temp;
    if (root == NULL)
        return;

    q_instance = init_q();
    enqueue(q_instance, root);

    while (q_instance->beg) {
        temp = /*(struct jsw_node *)*/dequeue(q_instance);
        fprintf(stdout, "%d\t", temp->data);
        if (temp->link[0])
            enqueue(q_instance, temp->link[0]);
        if (temp->link[1])
            enqueue(q_instance, temp->link[1]);
        free(temp); /* Here is my confusion */
    }

    free(q_instance);
}
```

Now, even if I `free()` the variable returned from the function `dequeue()` it causes me no harm. However, the value returned has been assigned dynamically in some other function. How doesn't it cause any problem with my tree? Isn't `free()` supposed to free the allocated space?

Comment: free() broken? Or your code? I know which my money is on....

Comment: @MitchWheat Couldn't find an appropriate title for the question.

Comment: Attempting to access something after you `free` it is a bug. Code with bugs in it will behave unexpectedly.

Comment: (Not reading your code but basing solely on your description:) `free()` makes that buffer available for reallocation but it does not overwrite the buffer (except in particular debug-based situations). Code that holds the stale pointer might be able to access the old memory, but that code is behaving in an undefined manner; it might get lucky and appear to work, it might cause a crash, it might disrupt other data and/or actions, it might.... you get the idea.

Comment: @mah I read the GNU libc documentation for `free()`, didn't find much about it in that, could you suggest any more references for it with some implementations as well?

Comment: I don't have any references for lack of the behavior you seem to think would exist... people don't generally document what a function doesn't do but since there's no documentation to state that the function clears the buffer, there's no solid reason to think it does. You can read the libc source to find an implementation, but first consider: if you were writing `free()`, would you want the overhead of clearing memory? That could get fairly expensive in all cases where a developer can simply call `memset()` themselves if wanted.

Comment: there is not standard-requirement to value-fill the a dynamic allocation when it is `free()`. If you want the content cleared, *you* have to do it. Some debug-heap-managers do it for you with special values to indicate prior content hints. outside of that (which you wouldn't be using in released code anyway) you're on your own. And by the sound of it this code needs a thorough thrashing with Valgrind.

Comment: without the rest of the code it's difficult to see if jsw_node_ptr value that is returned by dequeue is ever *referenced* again.  right now i don't see any issue.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, I think I will have to do that.

Comment: @AhmedMasud It has been referenced for deleting nodes in the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the C99 standard as an example here, which may or may not be what you're using. It should apply, though.  In the C99 standard, appendix J.2 lists undefined behavior. You'd want to note:

- An object is referred to outside of its lifetime (6.2.4).
- The value of a pointer to an object whose lifetime has ended is used (6.2.4).

mah alluded to this above - since the behavior is undefined, you don't know what will happen. In your case, the data is probably left behind and you're now improperly accessing free'd data which just so happens to still be accurate. Give it time and more malloc's and that data will likely/eventually change out from under you.

Edit: Link to the document for reference: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Comment: I tried allocating a lot of space through `malloc()` and finally got a wrong output. Thanks for the document.

Answer (score 1):

The space is deallocated and returned to the heap.  The data is not modified by `free()`, so the code may continue to *appear* to work (for a while at least).  However that memory is available for use by any subsequent memory allocation, and when that happens, either the tree data will be modified by the new owner and your tree will be broken, or you will modify the tree and the new owner of the memory will be broken.

The actual behaviour will always depend on when gets corrupted, when, and how the corrupted data is used. In the worst case you can corrupt the entire heap, and many things will be broken, in ways that are very hard to trace to the original cause.

Continuing to use memory that is free'd is not detected at runtime without using analysis tools such as Valgrind for example, and you may not observe any particular adverse behaviour at all.  This kind of bug may be in your code for a long time, only to cause a failure after some unrelated code change many months later.